# Under what conditions is the image an integral affine scheme contained in an open affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have a map $f : \text{Spec }A\rightarrow X$, where $X$ is a scheme, $A$ a domain. Under what additional conditions is it true that $f$ factors through an inclusion $U\subset X$, where $U$ is an affine open?

I feel like this should be true quite generally, but I'm not sure how to approach this. The domain condition is to rule out examples where $X$ is nonaffine and $\text{Spec }A$ is a disjoint union of all the points of $X$.

I'm happy to assume $X$ is separated.

Comment: The question is not a Yes/No question. So what do you mean by "I feel like the answer should be yes"?

Comment: @CraniumClamp Thanks, fixed.

Comment: It is true for any local ring A, domain or not.

Comment: A previous version of this question: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525639/every-textspec-r-rightarrow-x-factors-through-a-open-affine-subscheme).